# How to automatically insert optional curly braces in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

In C# (as in Java), curly braces are optional for e.g. if blocks and loops that only contain a single statement:

```
if (condition) DoSomething();
```

I am looking for a tool that inserts missing optional curly braces for my entire solution, turning the above code into something like this:

```
if (condition) {
    DoSomething();
}
```

I know that Eclipse can do this for Java. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a tool that can do this for C#. I would be grateful for suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: If you are not aware of such a tool, why did you tag the question with such a tool (Resharper)?

Comment: Maybe the OP mixed up Refactoring and Resharper..?

Comment: @Matten - maybe. And maybe the user is your sock puppet, not that I am saying the OP is.

Comment: @Matten - [Sock Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)). Like I said, not saying anyone is, but that's one alternative possibility...

Comment: @Oded no sorry, I'm not here to promote ReSharper :) And just to add this, we're set to use ReSharper with StyleCop integration which enforces us to use these curly braces for each ´if´ statement even if I think one liners are sometimes better readable than these four (three) line single-statement curly-braced ´if´s.

Comment: @Matten - StyleCop rules can be disabled.

Comment: @Oded No, StyleCop is included in the build process and produces a massive amount of warnings if not followed, and the steering committee for the stylecop rules file does not write one single line of code (saying they don't know what they are doing...).

Comment: @Oded To your first question. Maybe user1617243 want to say that he has ReSharper. And so I got this question in my ReSharper search result and could answer his question.

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) gives you the possibility to do such code refactorings by a short keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a *ReSharper Replace Pattern*.
Add a pattern to Pattern Catalog by (in ReSharper 5.1.3 ReSharper->Tools->Pattern Catalog->Add Pattern).

Then you write your pattern like so:

[image]

Unfortunatly this does not work for if-else. So you need another pattern like so:

[image]

Then you can set pattern's severity in *Pattern Catalog* dialog and can click *Search now*.

Answer (score 1):

With ReSharper, go to `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Braces Layout` and change neccessary options in `Force Braces` section to `Add braces`. Then find your solution in Solution Explorer, invoke context menu and choose `Cleanup code...` from it. Select `Default: Reformat code` and press `Run`. But be carefull! It would also reformat all code files in your solution. Be sure to backup if you do it the first time, just in case you wouldn't like ReSharper's default formatting. Maybe you would need to play with formatter settings to make it suit you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Brace Completer

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d

Comment: OP wants something that will add them to the entire solution - ie, existing code. BraceCompleter only adds a closing-brace when typing a new opening brace.